# How to get duplicate object array using lodash?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, lodash

I have Json array like attached image.

[multiple records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH9pw.png)

I want to find the name and get the value.
Currently i am using like this.

```
$scope.getDetailList = _.find(list, function(item) {
  return _.trim(item.name).toLowerCase() === _.trim(targetname).toLowerCase();
}
```

but i always get first objects values.

Comment: The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function

Comment: thanks Vivz. How can i get multiple record instead only first element ? I am very beginner on lodash and angularjs. thanks

Comment: You can use a for loop or angularForEach to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use _.filter to filter array and give results. use JavaScript trim() function. _.trim is not there in lodash.

```
$scope.getDetailList = _.filter(list, function(item) {
  return (item.name).trim().toLowerCase() === targetname.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: No fri. i want to retrive all the object based on item.name. Using filter the is no more result showing.

Comment: _.filter will iterate entire array like for loop. What is your targetname? And please provide full code.

Comment: targetname is array first property value.

Comment: _.trim() filter not exists in lodash. Use js trim. String.trim().